# How do I call a google cloud function from my javascript web application

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to call a Google Cloud Function that I've created from my Javascript Web Application using jQuery's .ajax() function.

Is there something special that I should be doing as when I call the end point I'm getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem.

I've used gsutil cors set and pushed a CORS file with an origin:["*"] but I'm still not getting it to work.

Any help would be most appreciative.

Comment: I've found the answer for anyone looking. It seems that CORS isn't the answer directly. The OUTPUT of the cloud function needs to SEND the correct headers so that jQuery.ajax() can work. Add this to your function and it should work.

res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add CORS headers to your actual HTTP endpoint. Here's one way to do it. In your functions directory:

```
npm install cors
```

Then in your code:

```
var cors = require('cors')();

exports.myHttpFunc = (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    // do the rest of your logic here and cors headers will be set
  });
}
```

This is, obviously, using the [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) package which has additional configuration options.